# How do I use a different view controller for each custom intent for siri shortcuts?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have prototyped siri shortcuts in my app using custom intents successfully.  I would like to define custom UI for different shortcut types.  For example IntentA would show a tall card with lots of labels and IntentB would show a short card with an image and one label.

I don't see any direct link in the code between the IntentViewController used in the MainInterface storyboard and the intent definition file.

If possible, I would like to have IntentAViewController and IntentBViewController defined in the MainInterface storyboard and handle them accordingly, but I don't see where I would tell the extension which viewcontroller or storyboard id to load for each intent.

If not possible, then what is the best practice for accomplishing multiple intent UIs? (I haven't found any tutorials that had more than one intent).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution inside the SoupChef example app from Apple.  Since there is only one main IntentViewController and one MainInterface storyboard, using intents you should detect the intent type and add the necessary view controller as the **child** of the IntentViewController.

From IntentViewController in SoupChef:

`/*         Different UIs can be displayed depending if the intent is in the confirmation phase or the handle phase.
         This example uses view controller containment to manage each of the different views via a dedicated view controller.
        */
        if interaction.intentHandlingStatus == .ready {
            let viewController = InvoiceViewController(for: intent)
            attachChild(viewController)
            completion(true, parameters, desiredSize)
        } else if interaction.intentHandlingStatus == .success {
            if let response = interaction.intentResponse as? OrderSoupIntentResponse {
                let viewController = OrderConfirmedViewController(for: intent, with: response)
                attachChild(viewController)
                completion(true, parameters, desiredSize)
            }
        }`

(where attach child calls addChild, addSubview, didMove and sets up constraints)

Comment: that really helps.